# How to use apache flink to stream all the kafka topic into database tables at one configuration via JDBC?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql, pyflink, flink-batch

Understand that flink sql can be achieve with jdbc connector but only one table at a time, is there any tools that flinksql can do a stateful streaming from kafka topics into database just like how kafka connect does?

Answer (score 0):

Each table in Flink SQL maps to a single instance of a connector.  If you define the source table using the Kafka connector and the sink table using JDBC, you should be able to write a streaming job with syntax like `INSERT INTO sink SELECT * FROM source`.

Comment: That will be huge effort, why not i just using Kafka Connect instead ?